Spilt dataframe colums and create new dataframe with Pyspark
I have pyspark dataframe with only one column having below data
Gourav,Joshi,"Sibley Grove,402,wmbley,London,United Kingdom",E1234,44982728930
Is there is any way to split this columns and create new dataframe like below.

I have tried to do this with split function but address fields getting spitted into multiple columns

CAUTION: The sample code below only demonstrates how to apply the split() function with a regular expression to achieve the desired result. However, the entire use case needs to be analyzed to understand whether spark.read.csv() from source would be a more suitable approach.
--- CODE ---
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, split

data = [("A,B,\"C,D\",F,G",)]
raw_string_column_name = "Raw"
split_array_column_name = "SplitTokenArray"
computed_column_names = ["FirstName", "LastName", "Address", "PinCode", "Phone"]

# Split
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, [raw_string_column_name])
df = df.withColumn(split_array_column_name, split(raw_string_column_name, r""",(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)"""))

# Compute columns
column_count = 5
for i in range(column_count):
    df = df.withColumn(computed_column_names[i], col(split_array_column_name)[i])

# Drop columns
df = df.drop(raw_string_column_name)
df = df.drop(split_array_column_name)

df.show()

--- OUTPUT ---
+---------+--------+-------+-------+-----+
|FirstName|LastName|Address|PinCode|Phone|
+---------+--------+-------+-------+-----+
|        A|       B|  "C,D"|      F|    G|
+---------+--------+-------+-------+-----+

